# How to keep track of the questions I've voted for deletion?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The title says all:

> I want to see what's going on with the questions I've voted to delete.

This is important for me, because I want to know if other users think like me, or maybe I've to review my voting criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply select "deletions" on votes tab in your profile.

Here is a link: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion

Here is a screenshot stolen from [this post on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go/130380#130380). (Although it was screenshot from the old version of the profile page.)

[image]

Maybe I should also add that you can see the votes you've cast there. But other users can't see this information in your profile.

Comment: I find that tab a little imprecise for my purpose, cause it mixes my deleted answers/questions with the one I've voted to delete, but anyway... it's better than nothing.

Comment: I think that is a useful feature. (People are often looking for their deleted posts.) I did not know about this, so I tried to look whether it is documented somewhere. I found [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/how-to-produce-a-list-of-my-own-deleted-answers/15239#15239) which links to [this post on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140328/dont-hide-undeletion-votes-cast-on-deleted-posts).

Comment: @user26857 That's because technically you also _vote_ to delete your own questions/answers. It's just a binding vote (when you can owner-delete the post; I guess if you have a closed question with an upvoted answer, you could cast a 10k deletion vote on that, which would not be binding).

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it. Thanks.